# Xamarin.Forms: use Relative Constraints inside Grid but without Relative Layout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, constraints

Is it possible to use constraints that reference other views inside *without* having them inside a Relative Layout?

In other words, is there a way to do this:

```
<ContentPage .... >
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition 
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
        Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,
        Factor=0.1,
        Constant=0}" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition 
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
         Type=RelativeToParent, 
         Property=Heigth, 
         Factor=0.1,
         Constant=0}"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

...note that this is a grid *not* inside a relative layout, but using RelativeLayout constraints. Is this possible, or something like it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Maybe it would be better to tackle the issue from that side.

Comment: There are various places this has come up for me, but the current one is trying to insure that a certain cell in a Grid layout is a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't apply `RelativeLayout` constraints to a grids rows or columns, as far as I know.

But there is a quite simple way to achieve the desired effect: Use `GridLength.Star`. All rows (the same holds for columns) that have a `*` height will have the *same* height. Anyway, a row with the height `2*` will be twice as high as a row with the height `*`.

To declare a row that has a heigh of `1/10` of the whole grid just use the following row definitions

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and equivalently for columns

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

You are using `9*` and not `10*`, since the `*` from the first row (column) and the remaining `9*` sum up to `10*` of wich is `*` `1/10`.

#### Edit

Since I missed a central point, that the `Width` and `Height` should be bound to the **same** property of the parent, let me expand my answer.

Of course you could embed the **`Grid`** itself in a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Grid RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression, Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}" 
          RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression, Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}">
        <!-- Elided -->
    </Grid>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This way, the `Grids width and height are bound to the same property`, which will make the `Grid` quadratic. Within the `Grid` you can use the start system to set the columns and rows relatively to the grid. Since the width and height of the Grid are equal, a `*` row will have a height equal to a `*` columns width. Does this help?

**Please note:** Depending on your overall layout `RelativeLayout` may be quite slow. ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance#optimize-layout-performance)).

Comment: Paul, thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the star system, but if you look at my example a bit closer you'll see that what it's doing can't be duplicated with the star system. In the example both the columns and rows are defining themselves relative to the same single parameter of the parent view, namely the width. Using the star system, columns set their widths based on the parent's width, and rows set their height based on the parent's height. But what you can do with relative layout constraints is set both of them based on the same single parameter, i.e. parent's height.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced Forget it. I re-introduced the `RelativeLayout` which does not seem to work for you. Keeping my edit in place, just in case it is useful for somebody else.

Comment: I like your solutions and your edit, perhaps this will be my only option. The resistance I have to relative layout is the documentation's own warnings about how it can slow everything down. I have a very complex Grid layout and putting a relative layout behind it would, I think, force every column and row to be subject to that slowness. The other option is something in the code-behind, I guess. At any rate I think you may be right.

Comment: If you add a post-script that people might want to avoid Relative Layout because it can slow things down I will give you this answer.

Comment: Great, thanks for the comprehensive response, including examples.